# Compare 2 factors among others

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

I am trying to polish the following sentences:

> The analysis time of an image depends on many factors. The size of an image is not as primary as its nature, because...

The context is:

1. There are many factors which determine the analysis time of an image.
2. Among them, we can think of "the size of an image" and "the nature of an image" (but there are still other factors).
3. For these 2 factors, our remark is that "the size of an image" is not as important as "the nature of an image".

So my questions are:

1. I'm not sure if "nature" is a good term to use for "image"...
2. is "primary" a good word here? or maybe we can use "decisive"?

Hope someone could help me write this sentence well, because it is a conclusion and quite important.

Answer (score 2):

The word "nature" is vague. It could mean the format, the number of colours, the subject matter, or something completely different.

Also, in this context, "depends on" is ambiguous. It could mean "has a dependency on" or "is influenced by"/"is determined by"

How about these for alternatives?

> The analysis time of an image depends on many factors, primarily its nature and, to a lesser extent, its size.
>
> The analysis time of an image is determined by many factors, the most important of which are the general complexity of the image and, to a lesser extent, its size.

Answer (score 0):

The terms often used in mathematics and engineering about traits that are intrinsic to an entity are

- characteristics
- attributes

In engineering, we perform *characterization* on a subject to determine traits that are intrinsic to an entity. The results of characterization processes are the *characteristics* of the entity.

*Attributes* would be the branches and leaves of a characteristic.

For example, a signal can be identified by its *characteristic* signature, where such signature would bear certain *attributes*.

Rather than primary, we use the word *intrinsic* - traits that appear to be indigenous to an entity.

Sometimes, but infrequently, we could use the term *primeval*, to describe traits that are initial to the birth of an entity. For example, the primeval patterns of information acquisition of a learning robot, or the primeval relationships of primeval entities of a newly initiated information repository designed to capture the information of a mutating process.

Rather than saying important, we should say

- dependent
- subsidiary
- subordinate

Therefore,

> The size of an image is a subsidiary attribute of one of the characteristics of the image.

*Characteristics* are perceived as traits that are long term or permanent. *Attributes* are ideas that are permanently found in characteristics, but values of such ideas frequently change. Like the colour of a car is a permanent idea of the car, but the value of the colour could be red, green, blue, etc.  OTOH, some people might view a car being red as the permanent characteristic of a car, since there is low possibility that the colour of a car would change before it is totalled.

According, to topological analysis in the relationship of characteristics and attributes, sometimes it is difficult to distinguish if a trait is a characteristic or an attribute. It is like an elephant in the room, with blind people, and how they would describe an elephant. It depends whether your analysis centres on the physique, trunk or tail, and so calling them the characteristics of an elephant, or the destructive consequences which would have the trunk and the tail as attributes of a characteristic destructive pattern.